# Can a malicious docker image running on GNOME-Boxes compromise the host?

Tags: security, docker, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

I'm using GNOME-Boxes to run a Fedora 35 guest inside a Fedora 35 host. If I ran a docker container, using the --privileged flag (among others), what's the most harm it could cause?

I read a malicious docker could indeed exploit a bare-metal system, so I assume it could access more than what it's supposed to in the guest machine. But what about the host?

Comment: If you are not patched against the recent "CVE-2022-0492", Affecting Cgroups, then probably yes. Since this will be fixed soon everywhere, i'm just commenting instead of answering. There may be other surprises lurking in UserNS.

Comment: @AlexStragies thank you. According to this last comment on red hat's [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2051505#c9) this CVE has been fixed for kernel 5.16.6 . I couldn't verify this claim though. Anyway, someone exploiting this way should be very unlikely though, right?

Comment: @Alex that’s a container escape, not a VM escape. The host would still be safe (assuming no other *virtualisation* vulnerabilities).

Comment: @Stephen Is OP not talking about containers? "... I ran a docker container ..."

Comment: @Alex I’d read the question as being about running containers inside a VM, but it could well be about running workloads inside containers *instead* of a VM... The accepted answer suggests the former, but perhaps that’s wrong. In any case, worrying about container escapes is pointless with privileged containers!

Comment: @Alex The container is running inside the VM, like Stephen was thinking. However the CVE you mentioned is still very relevant, in case the VM guest is also used to work and not solely for isolation purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I ran a docker container, using the --privileged flag (among others), what's the most harm it could cause?

`--privileged` means the container runs as root. That means the container can well do everything it wants to – the root user in the container is the root user of the full system. It can mount `devfs` wherever it like, overwrite your SSD. It can read all RAM, install nvidia drivers, download deepfake pornography, you name it.

However, that's just the container *inside* your VM, if I understand your question correctly. VM boundaries are actually boundaries (not just selectively namespace'd *features* of your kernel), so this is much harder to overcome. In the end, it depends on what you share with the host. But for example, if your host and the VM share CPU cores (they probably do!) and thus memory caches, the host is vulnerable to SPECTRE-style attacks inside the VM (which coincidentally might be the main reason why even small x86_64 VMs from hyperscalers give you two cores: that's the smallest hardware unit outside which caches aren't shared). Rowhammer still works, even if it's more likely the hammered pages are within the guest; of course, if you share GPU memory (through 3D accelerated guests), that's breaking a few walls. (GPUs and their drivers are especially nasty in that respect. There's gaming consoles that were jailbroken through exactly that mechanism - an accelerated guest being able to circumvent memory segmentation through the DMA engine of the GPU.)

In the end, though, that all is relatively unlikely to be usefully exploitable. Notice how from the top of my head, I'm only recognizing hardware bugs as breakers of VM isolation! So, you're pretty safe.

Comment: By the way, Fedora actually has better support for `podman` instead of `docker`, which has 100% the same syntax for its command line tools as docker, but has a much better working unprivileged mode. I've run a lot of containers, and I can remember exactly one podman container that I could not run unprivileged. Consider avoiding doing things `--privileged`, and consider using podman on Fedora.